# Get UV coordinates from UV map in blender

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am trying to get all the UV coordinates of each vertice to use in a OpenGL program to display a texture onto a cube. I was able to get the edges in blender by using the 2D cursor in the Uv editor. I get something like this:

```
static const GLfloat g_uv_buffer_data[] = {
    0.874f, 0.751f,
    0.874f, 0.499f, 
    0.623f, 0.499f, 
    0.623f, 0.751f,  
    0.374f, 0.751f, 
    0.375f, 0.499f,
    0.125f, 0.499f, 
    0.0124f, 0.751f,  
    0.623f, 0.751f,
    0.623f, 0.499f, 
    0.375f, 0.499f, 
    0.0f, 0.0f,  
    0.623f, 1.0f, 
    0.124f, 0.751f, 
    0.623f, 0.751f, 
    0.375f, 1.0f,  
    0.623f, 0.499f,
    0.623f, 0.249f, 
    0.375f, 0.249f, 
    0.375f, 0.499f,  
    0.623f, 0.249f,
    0.375f, 0.0f,
    0.623f, 0.0f, 
    0.375f, 0.249f,
};
```

Using the UV map in a openGL program to display some cubes with this UV data that I received from Blender using the same UV map gives this result:
[image: The application with the UV map and the UV daya]

This seems to be a cause in incorrect UV coordinates. I have tried searching online for a way to get all UV coordinates from the blender program to put together to make some data like the `g_uv_buffer_data[]`. In older versions of blender there seems to be a part at the bottom of the screen where it shows the UV coordinate of that vertice. I have not been able to find something like this is Blender 2.81. I know that this isnt some rendering problem within the UV map because it works fine on the generic cube in Blender.[image]

So how can I properly get the uv coordinates of the uV map to use it in my OpenGL program to map the texture to my cubes.

Comment: Have tried triangulating your mesh before collecting the edge data?

Comment: I have this produces similar results